# Hi, i have the same erro when i try to run a YOLOv8 model in azure machine learning with mlflow. Did you have solve the error?

Tags: azure, yolov8

This is part of my code and error:

```
run = mlflow.start_run()

run = mlflow.get_run(run.info.run_id)

mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name=run.info.run_id)

mlflow.autolog()

mlflow.log_param('initial learning rate', lear_rate)

model = pre_model.train(
        data=str(data_train),
        epochs=150,
        imgsz=640,
        batch=40,
        project=str(data_save)
        )

mlflow.end_run()
```

File "/azureml-envs/azureml_669e3f5d3a028adacb2c7717adab167c/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 133, in verify_rest_response
raise RestException(json.loads(response.text))
mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Response: {'Error': {'Code': 'ValidationError', 'Severity': None, 'Message': 'The request is invalid.', 'MessageFormat': None, 'MessageParameters': None, 'ReferenceCode': None, 'DetailsUri': None, 'Target': None, 'Details': [], 'InnerError': None, 'DebugInfo': None, 'AdditionalInfo': None}, 'Correlation': {'operation': '239feefe1355854189950d9897ad6d5b', 'request': '1d6715de9ed76595'}, 'Environment': 'eastus', 'Location': 'eastus', 'Time': '2023-06-22T20:27:09.6373897+00:00', 'ComponentName': 'mlflow', 'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE'}

Thank you for the attention